# App Engine Fails to Download Greater Than 33MB

Tags: java, google-app-engine, download, google-cloud-storage

The code below is straight from [google apis github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/bb3cfb437f216ca08f869f051a6cefd20a010e17/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage/StorageExample.java#L356) for downloading a file from GCS. I changed it to be able to download a file to my local computer.

If the file is larger than 33MB the app will stop attempting after 2 min or less. I think I read that app engine's limit is 32 or 33. I don't see anything in quotas to increase though. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to manage this?

```
    if (blob.getSize() < 1_000_000) {
        // Blob is small read all its content in one request
        byte[] content = blob.getContent();
        outStream.write(content);
        outStream.close();
    } else {
        // When Blob size is big or unknown use the blob's channel reader.
        try (ReadChannel reader = blob.reader()) {
            WritableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(outStream);
            ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(64 * 1024);
            while (reader.read(bytes) > 0) {
                bytes.flip();
                channel.write(bytes);
                bytes.clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Updated the try block although it must be downloading to GCS and not the local machine. java.io.FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the client to a direct link. A direct link has no limits. Ensure the link can be accessed by the client by setting the correct ACL's and/or permissions in GCP. Be careful about the link's security by not opening it up to the public.

response.sendRedirect("google.com");

Answer (score 0):

The max file size for App Engine is 32 MB (except for the Golang environment which is 64 MB). You cannot download a file larger than this from Google Cloud Storage (or any source). When deploying your app, you also cannot include a file larger than 32 MB in the deployment. This is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas). Look for the paragraph titled `Static data limit`

Comment: Thanks John. I've read that the Blobstore API can bump the limit to 2GB. Or, looks like a can serve a public URL from the GCS bucket directly? Looking for this answer now. Will post again if I can find it.

Comment: Yes, you can serve urls from Google Cloud Storage directly. This will require either public access or signed urls.

Comment: Yes! that works, thanks. I just need to make sure that the links are only available to the right users. If I redirect the user to a URL are they accessing that object as a user and not through the gservice account of the GAE anymore?


response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");